# Is there a way to know when all the processes started by my main java program has finished execution?

Tags: java

I have to do a benchmarking for performance difference between multi-threaded and multi-process architecture in java. This is the code i used to create new process

```
         for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
          {
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar myjar.jar " + input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in creating process");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

Is there a way to know when all the processes started by my main java program has finished execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: call [waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) for each Process:

```
for (Process p: processes) // you must save your Process references somewhere :)
   p.waitFor();
```

If p is already finished the method returns inmediatly. If it's not, it waits.

**Edit:** if you need to do other things in the mean time, execute this for/wait in another Thread. The thread will end the loop when all process are terminated, and you can do other things:

```
final List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

// start processes
for (...) {
   p = ...
   processes.add(p);
}

// create and start "watchdog" thread
new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      for (p: processes) 
         p.waitFor();

      // at this point all processes are terminated
   }.start();

// ok, I've started the "watchdog" thread. now let's do fun stuff...

// do my stuff...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Process.waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29), which will block until the spawned subprocess has terminated.

To use this you'd have to store all of the `Process` objects created in some sort of collection, and then loop over them calling `waitFor` - but that's not too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

for (...) {
   processes.add(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...));
}
volatile int processesCount = processes.size();

for (Process p : processes) {       
   new Thread() {
      public void run() {
         p.waitFor();
         processesCount --;
      }
   }.start();       
}

while (processesCount !=0) {
    //do nothing
}

//now all the processes were terminated.
```